I need to alter the input fields using AWK command - perform shell command operation on one of the input field & display
cat test-file.log |awk '{print $1,command executed on $1}'

Example - I am getting ipaddress  in $1 - so I need to display output like
Address |  Reverse dns lookup on the IP 
8.8.4.4    | dns.google


$1 - is count of specific IP logged
$2 - is IP Address
$3 - modified to display - the reverse dns operation on $1

I am not able to do reverse lookup on the filed $2(IP address)

Welcome to SO, thanks for sharing your attempts. Please do share Input_file sample in your question in text format also for making it more clear, thank you.

@RavinderSingh13 - this is the sample file - consisting of Count(No of hits on certain IP) as first column & second column is IP address   1 104.16.218.84 3 104.16.219.84 6 104.208.16.88 6 104.208.16.89 4 104.208.16.90 4 104.208.16.91`

[edit] your question to include all information including a [mcve] we can copy/paste to test with, don't add information in comments where it can't be formatted and could be missed. When you post sample input make sure it tests all of your requirements and that you provide exactly the expected output given that sample input.

As an aside, you want to avoid the useless cat

At times in your question you say the IP address is in field 1 and at others you say it's in field 2 - I'm going to assume it's in field 2 and you can change that as you see fit.
awk is a tool to manipulate text. A shell is a tool to sequence calls to other tools (and manipulate files and processes). "command executed on $..." sounds like you want to call some tool on the contents of a field and, if so, that's a job for shell, not awk, e.g.:
$ cat test-file.log
17 8.8.4.4


$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

ofmt='%-15s | %s\n'
printf "$ofmt" 'Address' 'Reverse dns lookup on the IP'
while read -r count ip rest; do
    printf "$ofmt" "$ip" "$(dig +short -x "$ip" | sed 's/\.$//')"
done < "${@:--}"


$ ./tst.sh test-file.log
Address         | Reverse dns lookup on the IP
8.8.4.4         | dns.google

Replace dig ... with whatever command you want to run on the IP address if that's not the one you wanted.
Alternative implementation if you have GNU column to make the output tabular (put the sed in the command substitution with dig as above or after the loop as below, whichever you prefer):
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

{
    ofmt='%s\t%s\n'
    printf "$ofmt" 'Address' 'Reverse dns lookup on the IP'
    while read -r count ip rest; do
        printf "$ofmt" "$ip" "$(dig +short -x "$ip")"
    done < "${@:--}"
} |
sed 's/\.$//' | column -s $'\t' -o ' | ' -t


$ ./tst.sh test-file.log
Address | Reverse dns lookup on the IP
8.8.4.4 | dns.google


-Thanks for quickly coming up with  solution using shell script.             can I have count of the ipadd as first value & IP address in second value & 3rd column as  the DNS of the IP  using AWK. sample output from firewall  logs
|count | ip-address|
|3      |   "dest_ip": "108.177.15.82"|
|30     |    "dest_ip": "142.250.178.27"|

[edit] your question to include all information including a [mcve] we can copy/paste to test with, don't add information in comments where it can't be formatted and could be missed.
